# Python multiple onclick events

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to be able to have both of my turtle onclick events function, but only one of them functions. I have a function that draws a square at the location the user clicks, and I have a close button that closes the program when you click it. Only one of these functions work at a time.

```
import turtle
import math
turtle.penup()
def square(x, y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)



def closebutton(location1):
(x,y) = location1
turtle.up()
turtle.setposition(location1)
turtle.down()
for i in range(2):
    turtle.forward(40)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(25)
    turtle.left(90)
turtle.up()
turtle.forward(7.5)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(5)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.write("close")

def btnclick(x, y):
    if x > 100 and x < 141 and y > -100 and y < -75:
        quit()
turtle.onscreenclick(btnclick)


closebutton((100,-100))
turtle.onscreenclick(square)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def square(x, y):
    # Check area is Close button
    if x > 100 and x < 141 and y > -100 and y < -75:
        quit()

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)
```

I think, at `square` function, we can check that is close button's area

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this the way you attempted, but we have to add the screen click handlers in a specific order and take advantage of the little-used `add` parameter:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

FONT_SIZE = 20
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

def draw_square(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)

def button_clicked(x, y):
    if 100 < x < 100 + text_width and -FONT_SIZE/2 - 100 < y < FONT_SIZE/2 - 100:
        quit()

def make_close_button(x, y):
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.setposition(x, y - FONT_SIZE / 2)
    turtle.write("close", move=True, font=FONT)
    width = turtle.xcor() - x  # pixel width of text we just wrote

    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(FONT_SIZE)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()

    return width

turtle = Turtle()

text_width = make_close_button(100, -100)

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(button_clicked)
screen.onscreenclick(draw_square, add=True)

mainloop()
```

But this approach makes it hard to disable the `onscreenclick()` event inside the event handler code.  That is, while one square is still being drawn, you can click elsewhere on the screen and start a second, interfering with the completion of the first.  To solve this we might try a completely different approach with a single event handler function that we can disable and reenable as needed:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

FONT_SIZE = 20
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

def draw_square():
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)

def button_clicked(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # disable event handler inside event handler

    if button.distance(x, y) < FONT_SIZE:
         quit()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    draw_square()

    screen.onscreenclick(button_clicked)

def make_close_button(x, y):
    button = Turtle(visible=False)
    button.speed('fastest')
    button.penup()

    button.setposition(x, y - FONT_SIZE / 2)
    button.write("close", move=True, font=FONT)
    width = button.xcor() - x  # pixel width of text we just wrote

    button.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        button.left(90)
        button.forward(FONT_SIZE)
        button.left(90)
        button.forward(width)

    button.penup()
    button.setposition(x + width / 2, y)

    return button

button = make_close_button(100, -100)

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(button_clicked)

mainloop()
```

Here we broke up the functionality a bit to have functions with specific duties.  And instead of figuring out if we clicked near the button, we left a turtle behind and just check the distance of the click from that turtle.

Both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages.